# Server compilation error on some pages apache mono

Tags: apache, mono, mod-mono

We have a .net web application running in fedora 6 under Apache & mono 1.1.18 version. So long it was working good. Suddenly I'm getting the following Server Error in some of the pages,

```
Server Error in '/' Application
Compilation Error
Description: Error compiling a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.

Error message:
(0,0) : error CS0006: Cannot find assembly `/tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/383ed40f/shadow-J7sRQf'
```

But please note, rest of the pages are loading properly. I know it has something to do with JIT compilation, but why it is happening on some specific pages. Also the error 'Cannot find assembly -----/shadow-J7sRQf' is something suspicious. The same error is displayed across all the browsers all the time.

I have not restarted apache or rebooted the system, as I'm not sure whether this error will occur again and i want to root cause it instead of just ignoring it. i didn't find anything on the httpd log also. I tried to Google it, but was unlucky to find anything specific. Can anyone help me on this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, mono 1.1.18 is really old!

If I were you, I would try to stop apache and clean everything in the temporary compilation directory /tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/
This should force mono to re-generate everything in this directory.

Then, restart apache and see if it helps.